# jQuery name select in chrome extension, multiple layers of quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, quotes

Chrome extension requires Javascript to be fired from

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { code: "js code here" });
```

This works fine doing a jQuery find by ID

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { code: "$('#testid').val('help me')" });
```

However, how do Is structure the quotes/apostrophes if I need to find by name?

```
$('[name="testname"]').val('please')
```

I'm unsure how to deal with the quotes/apostrophes when inserting it into the executeScript function. It seems I need a triple apostrophe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the quotes:

```js
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { code: "$('[name=\"testname\"]').val('please')" });
```

Or use template literals (using backticks):

```js
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { code: `$('[name="testname"]').val('please')` });
```